# Calculate sum of a column in power BI depending on a condition that should be evaluated over each row

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table which looks like this:
I need to calculate sum of all numbers in column :ADD , IF the number in column CHANGE is 0 AND column DELETE is 0.
[image: table]

The actual data looks like below. Its same as above. The items with red backets should be filtered out because there are values against delete and change for each unique number in MEMO column.

[image: actual image]

Comment: What is your expected output now with this new sample data? If there are Change/Delete for any MEMO, you wants to exclude all MEMO from the count?

Comment: I want sum of Total Count for each unique TSframe_ Memo where , Change OR delete is zero . So sum of total count for each unique TSframe , when only ADD exists and there is no change or delete for that memo number.

Comment: For example in above image i would want sum of Total_Count ignoring the memo numbers in red brackets.

Comment: for example 18779  has 1 ADD and 1 CHANGE. You wants to exclude all rows for 18779? As there are at least 1 DELETE/CHANGE. Right?

Comment: Yes , that is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a **Measure** as below to Exclude records from the list-

```
exclude = 

VAR current_row_tsframe_account = MIN(your_table_name[TSframe_Account])
VAR current_row_tsframe_memo = MIN(your_table_name[TSframe_Memo])

VAR find_delete_change_for_memo = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNT(your_table_name[TSframe_Memo]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[TSframe_Memo] = current_row_tsframe_memo
            && your_table_name[TSframe_Account] = current_row_tsframe_account
            && your_table_name[TSframe_Mode] IN {"CHANGE","DELETE"}
    )
)


RETURN 
IF(
    find_delete_change_for_memo > 0,
    "Yes",
    "No"
)
```

The above **Measure** will return Yes/No per row. You can now Apply visual/page level filter so that records only show where measure **Exclude = No**. Now this below measure will show your expected value-

```
total = SUM(your_table_name[TSframe_Memo])
```

Comment: Hi , well actually the table looks a little different , i had added the screnshot as reference. Here is how the actual table looks

Comment: I really appreciate your help @mkRabbani , i have put the problem in more detail. Can you please help me.

Comment: Hi @Bharath, I have updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: Thanks a lot @mkRabbani , I am getting mixed results like YES for some with change but for some memo numbers it is working correctly. At this point i am too ashamed to ask more help of you. I am studying you code to tweak it to work correctly. 
I really appreciate your help and effort. This has given me a good start. I will spend some time tweaking it.

Comment: provide sample rows you are getting wrong data. Please provide data in tabular format here, so that i can copy them to my pbi file. Alternatively you can provide me the pbix file (google/one drive) with issue you are getting. I can check them. Always happy to help. So dont feel ashamed :)

Comment: Thanks much @mkRabbani. Here is the file :  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rZVaKYUlUJoLB8_akJvNZ8GVtlFgp7zW0jF0lhurHwg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: checking the report

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222296/discussion-between-mkrabbani-and-bharath).